# Rearranging the order of ts files in m3u8 causes them to get stuck during playback

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, encode, http-live-streaming

I have one m3u8 file and several TS files.

The following is the actual output of the m3u8 file.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXTINF:4.027222,
test0000.ts
#EXTINF:4.004000,
test0001.ts
#EXTINF:4.004000,
test0002.ts
#EXTINF:4.004000,
test0003.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I rewrote this m3u8 in the following format, saved it, and played it.
Then the playback order of the video was exactly as I changed the m3u8.
However, the video playback does not work as expected and gets stuck.

```
#extm3u.
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXTINF:4.027222,
test0003.ts
#EXTINF:4.004000,
test0002.ts
#EXTINF:4.004000,
test0001.ts
#EXTINF:4.004000,
test0000.ts 
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

If I want to change the order of the TS files like this, how do I edit the m3u8 file?
Or can I use the ffmpeg command to change the order of the ts files and then recreate the m3u8 file?

Comment: Why do you want to change the ordering?

Comment: To be precise, I don't want to change the order; there are ts files with sequential numbers 1-2-3-4.

I would like to cut a part of the video without re-encoding.

For example, I want to remove the ts file in the middle of the video in the form of 1-3-4 or 1-2-4, but the video will be stuck as in this problem.

Do you know what causes this problem and how to solve it?
I would like to know if you have any information on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're not allowed to manually edit the playlist (or re-generate it using `ffmpeg` command). Due to [the restriction of HLS protocol (RFC8216)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-4.3.3.5) , media segments (the `.ts` files in your case) in the middle must NOT be removed when you set either value `event` or `vod` to `-hls_playlist_type` option in your `ffmpeg` command , even without `-hls_playlist_type`, it is still limited to change the playlist (and NOT including freely removing any media segment).

Quote from [General Server Responsibilities in RFC8216](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-6.2.1)

> The server MUST NOT change the Media Playlist file, except to:
>
> - Append lines to it (Section 6.2.1).
> - Remove Media Segment URIs from the Playlist in the order that they
>   appear, along with any tags that apply only to those segments
>   ([Section 6.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-6.2.2)).
> - Increment the value of the EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE or EXT-X-
>   DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE tags (Section 6.2.2).
> - Add an EXT-X-ENDLIST tag to the Playlist (Section 6.2.1).
>
> A Media Playlist has **further constraints** on its updates if it
> contains an EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE tag.  An EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE tag with
> a value of VOD indicates that the Playlist file MUST NOT change.  An
> EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE tag with a value of EVENT indicates that the
> server MUST NOT change or delete any part of the Playlist file; it
> MAY append lines to it.

Note that the `EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE` in your playlist related to `-hls_playlist_type` in `ffmpeg`

Comment: I read your reply. This text was exactly what I was looking for. I have manually edited m3u8 but in no case did it play correctly. I was looking for a way to edit m3u8. However, this text helped me to know that the idea is pointless. Thank you very much.